# Xamarin Forms - set page title to centre for Android

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms

To keep things looking consistent cross-platform, is it possible to have the page title showing in the centre in Android, similar to how it is on iOS?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             x:Class="gl_mobile_app.Views.Map.MapPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             Title="Map" >

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="backItem" 
                     Text="Back" 
                     Clicked="GoBack" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Comment: If with that "consistency" you intend to force an Android user to use an app that looks like an IOS one, that's non-native and non-natural for him, you'll get a lot of problems. The main XF goal is to make the app looks native on each platform

Comment: fair point, I'll take it back to the guy who requested it in the first place

Comment: Best choice! The app UI can be 'cross-platform consistent' but, the behavior and common elements as the answer buttons position on dialog boxes and page titles I don't think so. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Xamarin.forms app based on [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/) then you can easily achieve this using [Shell.TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/configuration#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar), define your title content, bind it or even style it as you like.

Inside your `ContentPage`:

```
<Shell.TitleView>
    <Label Text="Map" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

This way will avoid you to use a custom renderer.

Also if you need to apply some special adjustments platform-dependent you can use [OnPlatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential-xaml-syntax#platform-differences-with-onplatform).